# Creating a writable alias for a column in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

So, I have a table, for instance:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    blah VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);
```

and I want to rename the column `blah` to `bleh` -- the equivalent columns in the `bar` and `baz` tables are called `bleh`, and making the name uniform across tables allows me to simplify some of the code that accesses this database.  However, simply using an `ALTER TABLE` to rename the column will not do, as the resulting schema change is backwards-incompatible with code that hasn't been modified to match it.

So, I want to make it so that I have `bleh` as an alias for `blah`.  At first, virtual columns seem like a way to implement this:

```
ALTER TABLE FOO ADD (bleh AS blah);
```

However, the resulting `bleh` column can't be updated or inserted into, which makes it unsuitable for my purposes.  **Is there a way to create a writable (updatable/insertable) column alias in Oracle 11gR2?**

Comment: I suppose you could rename `foo` to `foo_base`, create a view named `foo` that mapped `blah` in `foo_base` to both `blah` and `bleh` in the view.  You shouldn't need to have an instead of trigger on the view unless there is something hinkey where an `update` might try to modify both columns.  The other option would be to create two physical columns in the table and just have a trigger that synchronizes the two until you are able to drop the old column.

Comment: @JustinCave -- that sounds like an answer...mind posting it as such?

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind.

Option 1 would be to rename `foo` to `foo_base`, create a view `foo` on `foo_base` and then expose the column in `foo` as both `blah` and `bleh` in the view.

```
alter table foo
  rename to foo_base;

alter table foo_base
  rename column blah to bleh;

create view foo
as
select id, bleh as blah, bleh as bleh
  from foo_base;
```

As long as you don't try to update both `blah` and `bleh` in `foo` in the same `update` statement, I wouldn't expect that to cause any problems.

Option 2 would be to add the `bleh` column to the table and then write a trigger to keep the two columns in sync in a before insert or update row-level trigger.  That means that the data would be duplicated and the logic would get a bit painful if an `update` statement tried to update both columns.  As long as you're only updating one or the other column, that should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a view, and in this view define an alias `blee` for column 'blah`, 
and then use this view instead of the table.

Simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    blah VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE VIEW foooo as
SELECT id, blah as blee 
FROM foo;

insert into foooo( id, blee ) values ( 1, 'aaaa' );

update foooo set blee = 'bbbb' where id = 1;

select * from foo;
        ID BLAH               
---------- --------------------
         1 bbbb
```